# Borel set that is not countable union or intersection of open or closed sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097859/explanation-borel-set?rq=1) previous question, one can read the following:

> It is important to keep in mind, by the way, that Borel sets are more than just countable unions and intersections of open and closed sets.

I tried to find an explicit example of a Borel set $A$ that can't be written only using a finite number of the following operations :

- countable unions of open or closed sets ;
- countable intersections of open or closed sets.

I know that there are [examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73296/example-of-a-borel-set-that-is-neither-f-sigma-nor-g-delta) of Borel sets that are neither $G_{\delta}$ nor $F_{\sigma}$, but I could write them using the two operations above.

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy) article on Borel hierarchy (if I understood it well), a Borel set can be obtained by a *countable* number of the two operations above.

Thank you for your comments!

Comment: When you say "countable union of open or closed sets", do you mean a countable union of sets of which some are open and some are closed?

Comment: @Henning Makholm : yes, that's it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear, because "countable unions *of open or closed sets*" and "countable intersections *of open or closed sets*" aren't "operations", they are sets.  I suppose you mean "countable unions" and "countable intersections", and what you're asking for is essentially a set that is not at a finite level ($\mathbf{\Sigma}_n^0$ or $\mathbf{\Pi}_n^0$) of the (boldface) Borel hierarchy.

In fact, there is an explicit construction of a set at every level ($\mathbf{\Sigma}_\xi^0$ or $\mathbf{\Pi}_\xi^0$) of the Borel hierarchy that does not belong to any earlier level: this is constructed by considering a "universal" such set, i.e., roughly one whose sections give every possible set of that level.  This is done for example in Kechris, *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* (1995, Springer GTM 156), §22.A, specifically theorems 22.3 and 22.4.  The construction is indeed explicit, though it is not very transparent.

Here's how I think I can simplify it slightly.  Instead of working in $\mathbb{R}$, it is much better to work in the Cantor space $\mathcal{C} = 2^{\mathbb{N}}$ of binary sequences (note that this is homeomorphic to the standard Cantor set).  A crucial fact is that $\mathcal{C}^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathcal{C}$ (by separating a binary sequence into its even and odd terms), and in fact even $\mathcal{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathcal{C}$ (using a bijection between $\mathbb{N}^2$ and $\mathbb{N}$).

Start with a universal open set in $\mathcal{C}^2$: to get one, consider an enumeration of finite binary sequences, and consider the set $U$ of those $(x,y) \in \mathcal{C}^2$ such that, for some $i$ for which $y(i)=1$, the sequence $x$ starts with the $i$-th finite binary sequence in the enumeration.  Since the set $V_i$ of elements $x\in\mathcal{C}$ which start with the $i$-th finite binary sequence gives an open basis $(V_i)$ of $\mathcal{C}$, this is a "universal" open set in the sense that every open set of $\mathcal{C}$ is $\{x : (x,y) \in U\}$ for some $y \in \mathcal{C}$.  The complement $F$ of $U$ gives a universal closed set.

Now we want to construct a universal $F_\sigma$, i.e., $\mathbf{\Sigma}_2^0$ set.  To do this, consider the set of $(x,(y_n)) \in \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $(x,y_n)$ (an element of $\mathcal{C}^2$) belongs to $F$ for some $n$: since every closed set of $\mathcal{C}$ can be obtained as $\{x : (x,y) \in F\}$ for some $y \in \mathcal{C}$, every $F_\sigma$ (=countable union of closed sets) can be obtained as a union of $\{x : (x,y_n) \in F\}$ for some sequence $y_n$ of elements of $\mathcal{C}$, that is, as the set of $x$ for which $(x,(y_n))$ belongs to the set I just described.  By using a homeomorphism between $\mathcal{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ we get a universal $F_\sigma$ set in $\mathcal{C}^2$.  Its complement is a universal $G_\delta$ (=$\mathbf{\Pi}_2^0$) set.

Redo the same construction as above, using the universal $G_\delta$ set instead of $F$ to get a universal $\mathbf{\Sigma}_3^0$ set.  Then do it again and again: this gives a sequence $U =: B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4,\ldots$ where $B_n$ is a universal $\mathbf{\Sigma}_n^0$ set in $\mathcal{C}^2$.

Finally, do the construction one last time but with $n$ varying: that is, consider the set of $(x,(y_n)) \in \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that, for some $n$, the element $(x,y_n)$ (of $\mathcal{C}^2$) belongs to the complement $B_n$.  Bring it to $\mathcal{C}^2$ (or to $\mathcal{C}$) using homeomorphisms: call this $B_\omega$.

Note that this construction is completely explicit: the axiom of choice was never used, for example, and given the choice of a few finistic bijections (between $\mathbb{N}^2$ and $\mathbb{N}$ or finite binary sequences and $\mathbb{N}$), the set is completely specified.

Now why can't the universal $\mathbf{\Sigma}_n^0$ set $B_n$ be $\mathbf{\Pi}_n^0$?  This is just a diagonal argument: if $B_n$ were $\mathbf{\Pi}_n^0$ then the complement of its diagonal $\{y : (y,y) \not\in B_n\}$ would be $\mathbf{\Sigma}_n^0$, and this clearly contradicts the universality of $B_n$.  So $B_n$ is no earlier than stated in the Borel hierarchy, and $B_\omega$ is a Borel set which cannot be constructed by finitely using countable unions or intersections.